# Change CartoDB tooltip offset

Tags: carto

How can I change the offset of the [CartoDB tooltip](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-5-0) from the cursor? When I add a 
 to the template content, the cursor overruns the tooltip and I would like to tweak the offset a bit so its 5,-5 pixels up and left of the cursor.

```
vis.addOverlay({
   layer: spillLayer,
   type: 'tooltip',
   template: '<p>{{type}} spill of <br>{{totvol}} gallons</p>'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing the CSS for the tooltip seems to do it.

```
.cartodb-tooltip p {
   margin-top: -10px !important;
   margin-left: -10px !important;
   }
```